# (Closed) Python CSV: (Master and Detail) Search and Insert Value From Detail File into Specific Column On Master File

Tags: python, csv, pivot

I am new in Python actually ):

I have task regarding Python and CSV where I need to add value into specific column on Master file after getting data from Detail file.

Let see sample Master File, Detail File and Output expected.

Master File:

[image]

Detail File:

[image]

Output Expected:

[image]

I have a few source-code to run it but not complete on this stage.
Let See what I have below:

```
from csv import DictReader
from collections import defaultdict


loaded = defaultdict(list)
month1=[]
month2=[]
month3=[]


def getdetailpayment(data):
    f=open(data)
    csv_file = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=",")
    for row in csv_file:
        print(dict(row))
    f.close()

def search_masterfile(data):
    word = input("Search name: ")
    f=open(data)
    my_reader=csv.DictReader(f,delimiter=",")
    for row in my_reader:
        for entry in row:
            if row[entry]==word:
                print(row)
    #insert value into this row on specific column
   
   
    f.close()   
                  
search_masterfile("csv/master.csv")
getdetailpayment("csv/detail.csv")
```

My plan to playing with dictionary where I assumed I can insert into Master file value and specific column based Detail file record existing. Unfortunately I am very weak of knowledge regarding this scope and I already try to get source-code from google but still not what I wants.

Please help me guys regarding this matter and I prompt thank you very munch on advance.

Comment: Please [do not post images of data](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), add the information as text (within code fences etc.) instead.

Comment: ooo.. sorry for that.. I thought it's more clear what I want to explain.

Comment: No, providing data to explain is great! Just not as linked images (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)). Pack paste them in a code block instead, such that it's easy to copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this with basic Python you could try the following:

```py
import csv
from datetime import datetime as dt

with open("master.csv", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    fieldnames = reader.fieldnames
    master = {(row["Name"], row["Key No"]): row for row in reader}

def to_month(string):
    return f"Month {dt.strptime(string, '%b-%y').month}"
    
with open("details.csv", "r") as file:
    next(file)
    for name, key, month, amount in csv.reader(file):
        master[name, key][to_month(month)] = amount

with open("result.csv", "w") as file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(master.values())
```

- The first step reads the master file (here `master.csv`) into a dictionary `master` with `(Name, Key No)` tuples as keys (for the merging). On the way the column names get picked up (`fieldenames`) for the writing later.
- The second step is reading through the details file (here `details.csv`) and updating the respective values in `master`. The `to_month` function transforms the month-strings into the corresponding key (column name).
- Then write the result into a new file (here `result.csv`).

You might have to adjust the filenames.

The result for the given input

- `master.csv`:

  ```
  Name,Key No,Month 1,Month 2,Month 3
  A,1,,,
  B,2,,,
  C,3,,,
  D,4,,,
  ```
- `details.csv`:

  ```
  Name,Key No,Month,Amount
  A,1,Feb-22,100
  B,2,Jan-22,80
  C,3,Feb-22,80
  D,4,Jan-22,100
  A,1,Jan-22,200
  C,3,Jan-22,90
  ```

is the following file `result.csv`:

```
Name,Key No,Month 1,Month 2,Month 3
A,1,200,100,
B,2,80,,
C,3,90,80,
D,4,100,,
```

If you have to do stuff like this often you might want to look into the [Pandas library](https://pandas.pydata.org).

Comment: Tqvm bro.. sorry for the late update.